# Sound doesn't play on Android Studio but in my app it sounds correctly

Tags: android, audio, android-emulator, media-player

I have a sound that I need to play at five correct answers. I use this code:

```
        if(numQuestion % 5 == 0)
        {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aplausos);
            mp.start();
        }
```

But when it comes to that lines, it arrives at `mp.start();` but I can't hear anything on the emulator, on my device I sound it perfectly.

It could be an emulator problem? When I see videos on youtube on the emulator it sounds correctly.

Comment: Maybe your PC soundcard volume is muted?

Comment: no, I'm listening to music and I stop when I make the quiz just for seeing if the sound is playing or not.

Comment: on my mobile phone it sounds perfectly

Comment: Then there must be some incompatibility on your emulator.

Comment: any idea to fix it?

Comment: Is there any error in the logcat?

Comment: I'd try deleting the emulator and recreating it

Comment: and it works? @Rotwang

Comment: no, there is no error in the logcat @Abhi

Comment: I can't guarantee it will work. But I'd try to.

Comment: Try disabling snapshot using `-no-snapshot`.